# ASP.Net Core Passing HttpRequestMessage Parameter always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

There is something weird with the passing parameter. The function is being called, I can debug it, but the request is always empty.

```
[EnableCors("SiteCorsPolicy")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LineBotController : ControllerBase
{
    private LineMessagingClient _lineMessagingClient;

    public LineBotController()
    {
        _lineMessagingClient = new LineMessagingClient(Config._Configuration["Line:ChannelAccessToken"]);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            var events = await request.GetWebhookEventsAsync(Config._Configuration["Line:ChannelSecret"]);
            var app = new LineBotApp(_lineMessagingClient);
            await app.RunAsync(events);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Helpers.Log.Create("ERROR! " + e.Message);
        }
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Is the HttpRequestMessage suppose to get every data from the request?

Some example of calling it:

```
    var data = {
        'to': 'xxx',
        'messages':[
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Hello, world1"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Hello, world2"
            }
        ]
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({request: data}),
        url: url,
        authorization: 'Bearer {Key}',
        success: function (success) {
            var x = success;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            var x = error;
        }
    });
```

the url: https://localhost/api/LineBot

Comment: show us how `url` is set

Comment: verify. is this asp.net-web-api-2.* or asp.net-core?

Comment: I am not sure if the url has problem because the function is being called and can be debugged.

Comment: this is asp.net core

Comment: Asp.net core no longer uses `HttpRequestMessage` or `HttpResponseMessage` so you need to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: I want to implement `LineBot` at my website. I just followed the documentation for implementing it in C#. It requires `HttpRequestMessage` as the parameter which then will call `GetWebhookEventsAsync()`. Is there I can do to achieve this in asp.net core?

Comment: I'm reviewing the github repo to see what that extension method does. you should be able to extract the desired data and perform the same functionality.

Comment: https://github.com/pierre3/LineMessagingApi/blob/master/Line.Messaging/Webhooks/WebhookRequestMessageHelper.cs

Comment: I see how I should do it, but then how can I get the same data as HttpRequestMessage in asp.net core way from the passed parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asp.net core no longer uses `HttpRequestMessage` or `HttpResponseMessage`. you would need to convert the code from the Github Repository for the `WebhookRequestMessageHelper`

https://github.com/pierre3/LineMessagingApi/blob/master/Line.Messaging/Webhooks/WebhookRequestMessageHelper.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Verify if the request is valid, then returns LINE Webhook events from the request
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">HttpRequestMessage</param>
/// <param name="channelSecret">ChannelSecret</param>
/// <returns>List of WebhookEvent</returns>
public static async Task<IEnumerable<WebhookEvent>> GetWebhookEventsAsync(this HttpRequestMessage request, string channelSecret)
{
    if (request == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request)); }
    if (channelSecret == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(channelSecret)); }

    var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var xLineSignature = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Line-Signature").FirstOrDefault();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xLineSignature) || !VerifySignature(channelSecret, xLineSignature, content))
    {
        throw new InvalidSignatureException("Signature validation faild.");
    }
    return WebhookEventParser.Parse(content);
}
```

so that it will work in .net core.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] string content) {
    try {              
        var events = WebhookEventParser.Parse(content);
        var app = new LineBotApp(_lineMessagingClient);
        await app.RunAsync(events);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Helpers.Log.Create("ERROR! " + e.Message);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

This is meant to be a simplified example which does not verify signature.